# Android-kSoap2 Response Parsing Issue

Tags: android, parsing, android-ksoap2

I am new to android and trying to parse this since 2 hours now.. Can anyone please help in parsing this response?…

```
getUserIdResponse{return=[member{member_id=123123; }]; }
```

This is a `Android-kSoap2` response which I get in a `SoapObject` variable..

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)retObj;
if (result.getPropertyCount() > 0){
    Object obj = result.getProperty("0");
```

in `obj` I get this..

```
[member{member_id=123123; }]
```

and whatever I do after this gives me exceptions of casting.

```
SoapObject j = (SoapObject)obj;
Vectormember resultVariable = new Vectormember(j);
```

this is what I've tried…

thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to parse the `Android-kSoap2` response using this

```
Object obj = result.getProperty(0);
Vector<SoapObject> vec = (Vector<SoapObject>) obj;
SoapObject so = (SoapObject)vec.get(0);
String memberId = so.getProperty(0).toString();
```

This gave me the exact Id i needed.. :)